# Extends FormGroup and handling subscription inside

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, unsubscribe

I normally create my forms this way:

```
export class ModelXFormGroup extends FormGroup {
  constructor() {
    super({
      property1: new FormControl()
    });
  }

  getRawValue(): ModelX {
    return super.getRawValue();
  }

  patchValue(template: ModelX) {
    super.patchValue();
  }

  get property(): FormControl {
    return this.get('property') as FormControl;
  }

}
```

If I need to make a property "disabled" depending on other, then in the constructor I can do like:

```
this.property1.valueChanges(newValue -> {
     if(newValue){
          this.property2.disabled();
     } else{
          this.property2.enabled();
     }
});
```

But I don't know how I could I kill those subscriptions...
I mean, I cannot use here ngOnDestroy and call this.subscription.unsubscribe().

Any way to do this inside the form?

Because the only alternative I'm thinking is like having a method in the form to unsuscribe manually all properties...

Component:

```
onDestroy {
    this.form.unSuscribe();
}
```

But I would like to make it transparent for the component..

Answer (score 1):

Hey I'm actually dealing always with this approach like 'MyNeedForm'.
So for handling subscriptions in my class wich is extending FormGroup:

initialize first an Subscription array in the head of your class:

```
private subscriptions: Subscription[];
```

add your subscribe stuff inside, for eg:

```
const valueChangesControl = valueChangeControl.valueChanges.subscribe(x => console.log("Value: ", x));
this.subscriptions.push(valueChangesControl);
```

write your function to cut them all:

```
cutSubscribtions() {
  this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
}
```

finaly in the OnDestroy() life cycle of your component where you instanciate your form, call the function:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  console.log("call destroy()");
  this.testForm.cutSubscribtions();
}
```

Take a look on this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5bzb6c?file=src/app/test.form.ts

Answer (score 0):

You could use `takeUntil`

```
private _destroyed = new Subject<boolean>();


ngOnInit() {
 // property 1
 this.property1.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this._destroyed) // specify takeUntil
  )
  .subscribe(value => { ... })

  // property 2
  this.property2.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this._destroyed) 
  )
  .subscribe(value => { ... })
}   

ngOnDestroy() {
  this._destroyed.next(true); // will unsubscribe all property that specify takeUntil
  this._destroyed.unsubscribe();
}
```

If want to use `valueChanges` in the class, maybe we could create a specific subject in the class as a trigger for unsubscription

```
export class ModelXFormGroup extends FormGroup {
  private _formDestroyed = new Subject<boolean>();
  
  constructor() {
    super({
      property1: new FormControl()
    });

    this.property1.valueChanges
     .pipe(
       takeUntil(this._formDestroyed) // specify takeUntil
     )
     .subscribe(value => { ... })
  }

  getRawValue(): ModelX {
    return super.getRawValue();
  }

  patchValue(template: ModelX) {
    super.patchValue();
  }

  get property(): FormControl {
    return this.get('property') as FormControl;
  }

  // define a new method here for unsubscription
  unsubscribe() {
    this._formDestroyed.next(true);
    this._formDestroyed.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

later in the component you could call this `subject` in `ngOnDestroy`

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.myModelXForm.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: I don't think I can implements OnInit & OnDestroy in a plain class. It should be a component , but as I said, I create specific classes for each form.

Comment: I think you shouldn't implement valueChanges in the class because it is part of a view logic that should be implemented in the component.

Comment: It is not actually part of the view, "disable" is a property of the form. The form class is independent from the component.

Comment: @user2992476 interesting approach you have here to use a form . What's the main reason you have a dedicated class for form? Btw, I've updated my answer, hope that the solution works for you.

Comment: Of course you can leave the declaration of the form inside the component. But I like to create getters for each field form, that way I don't need to access by formControlName or form.get('fieldPropertyAsString') which implees to pass the field name as hardcoded string.

Comment: In addition, I can reuse the formGroup class in other components that need it.